# Why alert works only on first row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use *Zebra Dialog* and I'm trying to make an alert set off every time a *Delete* is clicked.
The alert is only working when I click *Delete* in the first row. All rows below it does not work and I dont know why?

```
<table>              
     <tr>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td><a id="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
     </tr>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td><a id="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
     </tr>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td><a id="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#delete").bind("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.Zebra_Dialog("Do you want to delete?",{
            type : "question",
            title: "Question"
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Because IDs must be unique on context page

Comment: you're missing also 2 `<tr>`

Answer (score 4):

Id's must be unique.That's creating problems here.So to make your code work make some small changes by changing it's to class.

change mark up to

```
<table>              
     <tr>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
     </tr>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
     </tr>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
     </tr></table>
```

then in jquery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".delete").bind("click",function(e){  <-----  class selector
     e.preventDefault();
     $.Zebra_Dialog("Do you want to delete?",{
      type:"question",
      title:"Question"
    })
    //  send an ajax request here based up on the user selection 

  });
});
</script>
```

If you are a beginner please go through the [standard guide here.](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/)

Comment: Now, when I click _Delete_ alert is displayed, but when I click _Yes_ on alert nothing happens,row is not deleted...

Comment: You did'nt write any code,related it.How it gets deleted ?  Try to get result from `Zebra_Dialog`  and (yes/no) and if yes write code to delete the current `tr`.current `tr`  gets selected by `$(this)`

Comment: you have a lot of reading ahead of you! `var tr=$(this).closest('tr'); tr.remove();`

Comment: `<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $file['file_id'];?>">` and it worked until I put alert

Comment: @Timberman you said the href=# `e.preventDefault` prevents the link from working, but without it the javascript wont work, either put the alert on the new page or read about ajax

Comment: @Timberman what you are doing right now wrong,If user click ,immediately the record getting deleted.There is no point of asking yes/no. So please change your code such that ,If user click on yes then only send ajax request to server to delete the record from database.

Comment: How to do that, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Timberman  here is tutorial,please go through it.https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/ajax-quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

[ID attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) of an element must be unique value in a document, In your case all the delete links has the same ID. If you have multiple elements sharing a common behavior then use a common [class attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes) to group them together.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="#" data-id="1">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="#" data-id="2">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="#" data-id="3">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".delete").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $.Zebra_Dialog("Do you want to delete?", {
            type: "question",
            title: "Question",
            buttons: ['Delete', 'Cancel'],
            onClose: function (caption) {
                if (caption == 'Delete') {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'delete.php',
                        data: {
                            id: $this.data('id')
                        }
                    }).done(function(){
                        $this.closest('tr').remove();
                    }).fail(function(){
                        alert('there was an error while deleting the record')
                    })
                    //code required to delete the record from server goes in here
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H98nB/)

Comment: Now, when I click _Delete_ alert is displayed, but when I click _Yes_ on alert nothing happens,row is not deleted...

Comment: How do I do that when the caption is _Delete_ to call _delete.php_ file. This is my code until I put alert `<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $file['file_id'];?>">Delete</a>`

Comment: @Timberman see the update... there is a new attribute added to the delete button `data-id` it should have the `id` of the record to be deleted... then look at the script changes